# Add time.delta from list

Tags: python

I have a list of timedeltas:

```
liste1 = [datetime.timedelta(0, 10800), datetime.timedelta(31), datetime.timedelta(0, 10800)]
```

and find the sum of them i.e:

```
liste2 = liste1[0]+liste1[1]+liste1[2]
```

which returns what i want:`31 days, 6:00:00`
Now my problem is: liste1 gets updated with more time deltas, the length of which is not known in advance.
Liste2 obviously works because liste1[x] keeps my type and as soon as I try to slice and apply a sum, for example, i get a list instead, which doesn't work....

```
print(type(liste1[0]))
<class 'datetime.timedelta'>

print(type(liste1[:]))
<class 'list'>
```

So I can i iterate thru the list keeping the deltas in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to sum a list of timedeltas of any length. Something like this should work:

```
from functools import reduce
import datetime as dt

tds = [
    dt.timedelta(1),
    dt.timedelta(2),
    dt.timedelta(3),
]

zero = dt.timedelta(0)

r = reduce((lambda a, b: a + b), tds, zero)
print(r) # 6 days, 0:00:00
```

Update: as @jszakmeister pointed out, you can just do `sum(tds, datetime.timedelta())`.

Comment: No need for reduce, you can just use `sum()`: `sum(liste1, datetime.timedelta())`